# Do I need to add CHAR(13) in put_line() statement in Oracle to use fflush()?

Tags: oracle

I've read that to use `fflush()` function in oracle, every line in the output should end with a new line character. Will `put_line()` automatically introduce a new line character that needs `fflush()` to work ?

What is the new line character (`\r\n` or `\n` or depends on OS) that `fflush()` needs ? And what is the new line (`\r\n` or `\n` or depends on OS) character that `put_line()` introduces if at all it does ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `put_line()` adds the required new line character(s). [From the documentation for `put_line()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70942):

> This procedure writes the text string stored in the buffer parameter to the open file identified by the file handle. The file must be open for write operations. PUT_LINE terminates the line with the platform-specific line terminator character or characters.

That's really the difference between [`put()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70940) and `put_line()`:

> No line terminator is appended by PUT; use NEW_LINE to terminate the line or use PUT_LINE to write a complete line with a line terminator.

It's slightly confusing that the description of [`fflush()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_file.htm#ARPLS70913) refers to just "a newline character" while `put_line()` refers to "line terminator character or characters", but they do mean the same thing - to flush the buffer must end with the operating-system line terminator character(s).

Note that it means the database server's operating system, not your client operating system, since `utl_file` (and all PL/SQL) is on the server and doesn't know anything about the client environment. It's generally safer to use `put_line()` or `new_line()` than to manually add `\n` or `\r\n`; even if you know the OS your database is running on now, it may move to a different OS one day.

Comment: Thanks @Alex. Pretty clear now. I've one more question. Will there be any performance issue if I use `fflush()` for every 500 rows when I've 5 million rows to be written into a file. If yes, what kind of issues do I have to face ?

Comment: @learner1 - there will be some effect on performance; you're flushing manually so you aren't (always) filling the buffer. How much depends partly on the size of the buffer and how much data is written for each row - i.e. how often the buffer fills and is flushed automatically, compared with how empty it is when you manually flush. Whether that's an *issue* is another mater; presumably you have a reason for wanting to flush manually at all. I'd time it both ways, and maybe adjust the buffer size, to see if it's acceptable - and if it's really needed at all.